# Unioned queries with subqueries disobeys order by clauses

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a query:

```
select * from (select top 100 percent ... from [table] 
    where [field1] is not null
    order by [field1]) a 
union all 
select * from (select top 100 percent ... from [table]
    where [field1] is null 
    order by [field2]) b
```

The subqueries are ordering their results correctly. I want the exact results of the first subquery, THEN the exact results of the second subquery. However, I'm actually getting the concatenated results ordered in some odd way that I can't even discern a pattern from. I have [field2] values scattered about the result set apparently at random.

How can I get the first query results on top, and the second query results on bottom?

Edit: To clarify, I want the top query ordered by its own conditions, and *then* I want the bottom query ordered by its own conditions.

Comment: `top 100 percent` seems kind of useless to me...

Comment: @Rahul: Then I get "incorrect syntax near the keyword 'union'".

Comment: @Daniel: You must specify a TOP when putting an ORDER BY in a subquery. I don't know why.

Comment: @tsilb: I don't think that is the case. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa213252%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) for example.

Comment: @tslib, my mistake .... sorry ... the field must be in select if it's to be ordered

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure, whether or not UNION ALL is meant to preserve the order of rows.
You can force the order you want by using the following statement:

```
select [field1] from
(
    select * from
    (select 1 as query_number, [field1], [field1] as [order_field] from [table] 
        where [field1] is not null) a 
    union all 
    select * from
    (select 2 as query_number, [field1], [field2] as [order_field] from [table]
        where [field1] is null) b
)
order by query_number, [order_field];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from (select top 100 percent ...,  1 AS q from [table] 
    where [field1] is not null
    order by [field1]) a 
union all

select * from (select top 100 percent ...,  2 AS q from [table]
    where [field1] is null 
    order by [field2]) b

order by q
       , CASE q
           WHEN 1 THEN fieldX   
           WHEN 2 THEN fieldY
         END
```